# Detecting centers of circles from camera images

Tags: image-processing, ionic-framework, hough-transform

So I'm developing an Ionic app that uses the phone camera to detect circles on fabric, like the picture below:
[image]

Where the max size is a 3x3 grid and there are 4 different colors (lightblue, darkblue, lightgreen and darkgreen). Basically, I've broken the problem down into 3 steps:

1. Get the center of each circle.
2. Get the color at the center of each circle
3. Using the positions of each circle's center, create a representation of the pattern as a 2d array

My problem is figuring out the best way to achieve step 1. I've looked into the Hough Transform and I can't find very good resources for Javascript. If there is an easier or better way than using the Hough transform I would be very grateful to know.

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of that software is? If those blobs are designed for being detected by a camera they are a very bad design. They are barely circles btw. Distorted, viewed from an angle... not very good for Hough transform. You should use a labeling algorithm and use their centroids.

Comment: Each pattern represents a story. The user scans the dot pattern, and the pattern associated with that story is shown.

Comment: any particular reason why you don't use a common 2d-code? or using different shapes instead of different colours would also increase robustness a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image Segmentation with Watershed Algorithm which described in 
[here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)

Comment: So you linked to OpenCV. Is this compatible with Ionic/Angular?

Answer (score 1):

In this type of image, you can do:

1. Color thresholding in order to find each pattern
2. (optional) opening + closing in order to clean a little bit your image if the thresholding result is not perfect.
3. Connected component labeling (see the Union-Find algorithm) in order to separate each component.
4. Then you have all the patterns, so you can easily find the centers and colors.

Comment: How would I do this in the context of Angular/Ionic? What library/technology would be compatible with this method?

Comment: pretty much every image processing library should support these methods

Comment: Sorry, I don't use ionic, but these operations are definitely standard in image processing, and are implemented in most of the libraries. I expect some of them are compatible as said Piglet.